# Store some text persistently in a browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a Javascript library to [FluidDB HTTP API.](http://doc.fluidinfo.com/fluidDB/api/http.html)

Since FluidDB API does not support JSONP I am forced to use AJAX and hence to develop a firefox extension to workaround AJAX's same origin policy.

My solution is to include a HTML file inside the extension. That HTML file displays a simple form where the user could enter the username, password and the other GET/POST data that forms a request.

I load the HTML file using the chrome URL.

When the user enters his username and password I want to store it somewhere persistently and spare him the trouble of having to enter it everytime. I tried creating cookies but it did not work as the webpage is not a valid domain.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: yes, i am shouting: DO NOT STORE THE PASSWORD AS A COOKIE!

Answer (score 1):

Once I had the same issue "cookie-less Session Variables in JavaScript", while working on my project.so came across one method called `window.name="some value"`,take a look of following link which i had digg during my project.Hope it will be useful for you..
please dont ignore the caveats.
[cookie-less Session Variables in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/09/02/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/)

Answer (score 1):

I only just ran across this question. FluidDB does (now) support JSONP:

http://doc.fluidinfo.com/fluidDB/api/http.html#support-for-jsonp

Terry

Comment: Oh cool. Let's see if I can make some time to work on it. Thanks!!